# SalesForce Deployments taking around 75 minutes to complete

Tags: ant

I am using CumulusCI to deploy packaged code and objects to a few orgs, as part of continuous integration.

However, these deployments are taking sometimes up to 72 minutes, this is both locally from my PC and automatically through Codeship.com.

Has anyone experienced this before? I have check trust.salesforce.com and there are no issues on any of the instances I am using. This has been happening for around a week now. Any ideas?

The Log looks like:

```
[sf:deploy] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Pending
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Pending
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Pending
(Continued..)
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Pending
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Pending
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Pending
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Succeeded
```

Comment: Check for slow running tests. It is not an unreasonable amount of time.

Comment: It does not get as far as the tests when its running. I have updated my question with a sample log.

Comment: please check if any of your users have enabled debug logs in production, it will delay the deployment process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool to see you're playing around with CumulusCI :)  FYI, there's also a CumulusCI group I created in the Success Community where you can find some others using it.

I've never seen this in any of our deployments.  The deploy portion of our deployments usually takes about 2-3 minutes.  Are you deploying to a Developer Edition org or to a Production org?  If it's a production org, I believe the tests run automatically on the deployment.  I've never run a deployment from ant into a production org so I don't know whether or not the output will show anything about the automatically run tests.

If you are deploying to production, you could verify whether it's the automatic execution of tests by doing a deployment into a Developer Edition org and seeing if it runs faster.

The only other possibility I can think of is that you've got a ton of large metadata files, perhaps lots of StaticResources, but even in that case it doesn't seem like it would take that long.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it does look like there is a massive problem since Summer 15' release - even Eclipse IDE and MavensMate is failing to save to server :(. We have around 30 devs in the company working across various orgs and instances and we are all facing issues :(

Comment: Are these deployments to production orgs or to DE orgs?

Comment: Both. Looks like the issue is clearing up, speeds are back to less than 10 minutes as of this morning. Nothing was posted on trust though :/